# Youtube Autosearch with individual output v2 to v3 upgrade

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I got the following problem I want to upgrade the old version2 Youtube autosearch script to version3 but can't figure out what I do exactly wrong need some help. It gives out this failure message:

```
test.php:27 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined
    at Object.success (test.php:27)
    at j (jquery-latest.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-latest.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery-latest.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery-latest.min.js:4)
```

This is my code so far only replaced the url and used api key. But every time I keydown on the input field, it prints out the above error.

```
<input id="searchquery" />
<div id="results"></div>

<!-- Include the latest jQuery library -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $('#searchquery').keyup(function () {

    // the search term
    var q = $('#searchquery').val().trim();

    // container to display search results
    var $results = $('#results');

    // YouTube Data API base URL (JSON response)
    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=video&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"



    $.getJSON(url + "&q=" + q, function (json) {

      var count = 0;

      if (json.data.items) {

        var items = json.data.items;
        var html = "";

        items.forEach(function (item) {


            // Include the YouTube Watch URL youtu.be 
            html += '<p><a href="https://youtu.be/' + item.id + '">';

            // Add the default video thumbnail (default quality)
            html += '<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/' + item.id + '/default.jpg">';

            // Add the video title and the duration
            html += '<h2>' + item.title + ' ' + item.duration + '</h2></a></p>';
            count++;

        });
      }

      // Did YouTube return any search results?
      if (count === 0) {
        $results.html("No videos found");
      } else {
        // Display the YouTube search results
        $results.html(html);
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

After debugging your code using JS Fiddle, here what I have discovered.
I have tried to log the response of `json` obj:

```
{
etag: ""XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/Ou9EhMuIjRoTlkkxhthG81p96AE""
items: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
kind: "youtube#searchListResponse"
nextPageToken: "CAUQAA"
pageInfo: {totalResults: 1000000, resultsPerPage: 5}
regionCode: "PH"
}
```

This means your `json.data.items` will be undefined because there's no property `data` inside the object.

Try to change you code to `json.items`. This will fix your error.
I would like to suggest if you encountered another error, try to debug your code using **Chrome dev tools** or using `console.log`.

Comment: altight done this but how to find the items title and duration etc in my code he only output undefiened objects

Comment: You can try to iterate the items arrays and find those attributes.

Comment: could you give an advice how to do it ?

Comment: I think you've mistaken about the response of Search API. For more understanding, you can read at [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search). There's no duration attribute there, only title of the channel and the video.  You can also view the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/923214/). I hope it helps.